# Output first string, not all children's strings

Tags: xslt

I'm having an issue with a bit XSLT code I'm working with for a client. I cannot change the schema, as a flash application depends on it and making any changes would break the ActionScript. It's unfortunate.

This is my first foray into XSLT and I'm admittedly incompetant with it, so I was hoping the community could help me out.

This is the schema (XML file):

```
<statement title="Click on your Answer" answer="true">
   True or False: The question asked is here.
      <feedback>
         <answerTrue sound="">
            The response if the user answered true is here.
         </answerTrue>
         <answerFalse sound="">
            The response if the user answered false is here
         </answerFalse>
      </feedback>
</statement>
```

When I try to access the "statement" like this (XSLT):

```
<div id="statement">
 <xsl:value-of select="statement" />
</div>
```

It displays the "answerTrue" and "answerFalse" nodes along with it. I would like to *only* display the text "True or False: The ques...". If anyone knows of a tag I can use to display the statement without displaying the child elements, I'd be eternally grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Kinda confused here. The XSL fragments you have posted are different and the second one appears to be what you want to do. What's the issue again? What tag are you talking about - HTML or XSL? What exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I can see how that's confusing. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
normalize-space(/statement/text()[1])
```

Comment: `[1]` is an abbreviation for `[position() = 1]` . `/statement/text()[1]` means: select the first text-node child of the `statement` element which is the top element of the document.