# How can I get just the first, higher level, string?

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, value-of

I have this (token of) XML file of which I want to print just the "Print this" string, ignoring what follows:

```
<tag1>
   Print this
   <tag2>
      Do not print this
   </tag2>
</tag1>
```

In my XSL file, with this command I get both the contents of `tag1` and the contents of `tag2` printed:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tag1"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: exact duplicate of [Output first string, not all children's strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227720/output-first-string-not-all-childrens-strings)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and for a correct and more precise solution than the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my XSL file, with this command I
>   get both the contents of tag1 and the
>   contents of tag2 printed:
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="tag1"/>
> ```
>
> How can I get just the first, higher
>   level, string?

Your code produces the string value of the `tag1` element, which by definition is the concatenation of all text-nodes-descendents of the element.

**To produce just**

> the "Print this" string

**you need to specify an XPath expression that selects only the respective text node**:

```
/tag1/text()[1]
```

Specifying `[1]` is necessary to select only the first text-node child, otherwise two text-nodes may be selected (this is an issue only in XSLT 2.0 where `<xsl:value-of>` produces the string values of all nodes specified in the `select` attribute).

Further, the above expression selects the whole text node and its string value isn't `"Print this"`.

The string value actually is:

```
"
   Print this
   "
```

and exactly this would be output if you surround the `<xsl:value-of>` in quotes.

**To produce exactly the wanted string `"Print this"` use**:

```
"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(/tag1/text()[1])"/>"
```

Answer (score 3):

`value-of` of an element will give you the value of it's text nodes and that of it's descendants.  If you just want the immediate `text()` node of the element, use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tag1/text()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<xsl:value-of select="tag1/text()"/>` will select all text nodes under `tag1`